# Merge several dictionaries creating array on different values

Tags: python, dictionary, mergeddictionaries

So I have a list with several dictionaries, they all have the same keys. Some dictionaries are the same but one value is different. How could I merge them into 1 dictionary having that different values as array?

Let me give you an example:

let's say I have this dictionaries

```
[{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':4},{'a':1, 'b':3,'c':3},{'a':1, 'b':3,'c':4}]
```

My desired output would be this:

```
[{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':[3,4]},{'a':1, 'b':3,'c':[3,4]}]
```

I've tried using `for` and `if` nested, but it's too expensive and nasty, and I'm sure there must be a better way. Could you give me a hand?

How could I do that for any kind of dictionary assuming that the amount of keys is the same on the dictionaries and knowing the name of the key to be merged as array (`c` in this case)

thanks!

Comment: What's the logic here? Why merge the `'c'` keys but separate the `'b'`?

Comment: Because I want to merge when all keys are the same except key c.

Comment: Just n advice: you will be better creating an array inconditionally - it is easier to deal later with some arrays containing  a single element than with "this time it is an array, this time it is not"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the `c` values by `a` and `b` tuple keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 4},
    {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 3},
    {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 4},
]

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in lst:
    d[x["a"], x["b"]].append(x["c"])

result = [{"a": a, "b": b, "c": c} for (a, b), c in d.items()]

print(result)
```

Could also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if `lst` is already ordered by `a` and `b`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 4},
    {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 3},
    {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 4},
]

result = [
    {"a": a, "b": b, "c": [x["c"] for x in g]}
    for (a, b), g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter("a", "b"))
]

print(result)
```

Or if `lst` is not ordered by `a` and `b`, we can sort by those two keys as well:

```
result = [
    {"a": a, "b": b, "c": [x["c"] for x in g]}
    for (a, b), g in groupby(
        sorted(lst, key=itemgetter("a", "b")), key=itemgetter("a", "b")
    )
]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 4]}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': [3, 4]}]
```

---

### Update

For a more generic solution for any amount of keys:

```
def merge_lst_dicts(lst, keys, merge_key):
    groups = defaultdict(list)

    for item in lst:
        key = tuple(item.get(k) for k in keys)
        groups[key].append(item.get(merge_key))

    return [
        {**dict(zip(keys, group_key)), **{merge_key: merged_values}}
        for group_key, merged_values in groups.items()
    ]

print(merge_lst_dicts(lst, ["a", "b"], "c"))
# [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 4]}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': [3, 4]}]
```

Comment: The solution is nice but i'm trying to appying to my side where i have a list with dictionaries and i get `first argument must be callable or None` .
On the other hand, how would it be if the dictionaries would have a lot of keys, say 30?

Comment: @Capie Hmm not sure, these are working for me. What Python version are you on?

Comment: 3.6.9 it works for me for that exact code  but not for my custom data :D

Comment: How could I automate this for any kind of dictionary with any amount of keys, just knowing that all dicts have same amount of keys and knowing which key should be merged as array?

Comment: @Capie Should be a similar approach to above. Just filter all the keys that are not being merged into an array, and use them as the key. Key might end up being big, but that would be an easy way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Capie Could you try my updated solution? It passes a list of keys, and a merge key.

Comment: +1 for {**dict(zip(keys, group_key)), **{merge_key: merged_values}}. I always kinda forget this syntax! So much to learn in python always! :)

Comment: @Mahori Thanks for the +1. I would upvote your answer, but I've ran out of upvotes for the day. I will upvote tomorrow. Yeah always cool syntax to learn in python. I like the `**` syntax for merging because I'm too lazy to merge with `update()` or something.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a temp dict to solve this problem -

```
>>>python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 

>>> di=[{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':4},{'a':1, 'b':3,'c':3},{'a':1, 'b':3,'c':4}]
>>> from collections import defaultdict as dd
>>> dt=dd(list) #default dict of list
>>> for d in di: #create temp dict with 'a','b' as tuple and append 'c'
...     dt[d['a'],d['b']].append(d['c'])
>>> for k,v in dt.items(): #Create final output from temp
...     ol.append({'a':k[0],'b':k[1], 'c':v})
... 
>>> ol #output
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 4]}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': [3, 4]}]
```

> If the number of keys in input dict is large, the process to extract
>   tuple for temp_dict can be automated -

if the keys the define condition for merging are known than it can be simply a constant tuple eg.

```
keys=('a','b') #in this case, merging happens over these keys
```

If this is not known at until runtime, then we can get these keys using zip function and set difference, eg.

```
>>> di
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}]
>>> key_to_ignore_for_merge='c'
>>> keys=tuple(set(list(zip(*zip(*di)))[0])-set(key_to_ignore_for_merge))
>>> keys
('a', 'b')
```

At this point, we can use map to extract tuple for keys only-

```
>>> dt=dd(list)
>>> for d in di:
...  dt[tuple(map(d.get,keys))].append(d[key_to_ignore_for_merge])
>>> dt
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {(1, 2): [3, 4], (1, 3): [3, 4]})
```

Now, to recreate the dictionary from default_dict and keys will require some zip magic again!

```
>>> for k,v in dt.items():
...  dtt=dict(tuple(zip(keys, k)))
...  dtt[key_to_ignore_for_merge]=v
...  ol.append(dtt)
... 
>>> ol
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 4]}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': [3, 4]}]
```

This solution assumes that you only know the keys that can be different (eg. 'c') and rest is all runtime.

Comment: What if the dictionaries have more keys than a and b, say 30? I would have to check that dictionaries have equal values for 29 keys and then merge them creating array on desired key (`c` in this case)

Comment: See the updated solution, it is completely generalized, doesnt even assume any order of keys!

Comment: What about amount of keys as i mentioned on previous comment?

Comment: This will work for any number of keys. keys=tuple(set(list(zip(*zip(*di)))[0])-set(key_to_ignore_for_merge)) will extract the keys from input list of dictionaries. It could be 30 or 3000!